# Is it necessary to check null when use 'is' operator

Tags: kotlin, typechecking

I have an instance which can be null. Fox example

```
var str: String? = null
```

So I need to check if str is String. Do I need to check for null if I use the is operator.
First option:

```
if(str is String) {}
```

Second option:

```
if(str != null && str is String) {}
```

Please help me which way is better to use ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `is` operator is safe and returns false in the case you supply a null instance

https://pl.kotl.in/HIECwc4Av

Somewhere, you HAVE to nullcheck.
Kotlin provides many ways to enforce non-null:

Use a non-null type:

```
var nonNull : String = ""
var nullable : String? = "" // notice the ?

nullable = null // works fine!
nonNull = null // compiler error
```

and if you encounter a nullable type, you can use `let {} ?: run {}` construct to unwrap it and execute your code with a non-nullable:

```
nullable?.let { // use "it" to access the now non-null value
    print(it)
} ?: run { // else
    print("I am null! Big Sad!")
}
```

Kotlin strictly distinguishes between nullable `T?` and nonnull `T`.
Use `T` wherever possible to avoid null checks.

Comment: Yes, but isn't it worth checking for a null  to avoid doing unnecessary type checking?

Comment: @testovtest, `is` operator translates into `INSTANCEOF` bytecode op, which also checks for null. There is no real benefit in checking for null before using `is`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to check about NULL before using 'is' for the Type check. As mentioned above, it will just return FALSE in case of a NULL-Object.

Kotlin will also do a smart cast, when the if-statement is TRUE, so you can continue with a non-NULL Object casted to the checked Type (if possible)

```
if(anyObject is String){
    anyObject.contact(anotherString)
    ...
}
```

For safe and unsafe Type checks and casts may have a look at:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html